# Law of Demeter-Inputting parameters

Tags: java, string

i was running the PMD tool for my code and checking it for a simple program that inputs two strings for beginning purposes.when i do something like `a=in.nextLine();` it shows object not created locally.Can you help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a, b;
        a = in.nextLine();
        b = in.nextLine();

        in.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Use `String a = ...`, `String b = ...`. Never use this C-style syntax. In an ideal world, an variable is assigned the moment it's declared - this is not always possible (conditional assignment, etc) but is a good goal to aim for.

Comment: The code is working fine..!!

Comment: works fine for me too

Comment: The question is not about working fine or not, it is about code quality, guys...

Comment: yeah i know it works fine i have been using it for ages..:) as dam said it's about code quality.

Comment: Well, the object isn't created locally. That's absolutely true. Is it important? I don't think so. Perhaps you can change the settings on your PMD tool.

Comment: i think it is it shows that in urgent violations meaning it  has a vulnerability of scale 3 out of 5 maybe some expert pmd user can tell:)

Comment: @MohitMiglani PMD is not a "find vulnerabilities in my code" tool. It's a "write clean code" tool. It's telling you that this code has not had a shower for 3 days; which is most of the way to not having had a shower for 5 days after which point it makes no difference how many days it hasn't showered for because no one is going to want to be near it anyway.

Comment: Waiting for an answer:)